# What method(s) are needed from an imageview to save its current instancestate?

Tags: android, imageview, instance

I have an imageview whose image is selected and changed by the user and I need to save its instancestate so the current image is displayed when the screens orientation changes or they switch to a different activity etc. I've been searching for a while but cant figure out the method(s) I need to use to pull the information from the imageview that I need to pass into the onSaveInstanceState bundle. Could someone point me in the right direction please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing that you can "use to pull the information from the imageview". You need to know the source of the image in the `ImageView` by some other means, and elect to save that in your instance state.

For example, the code that updates the `ImageView` could store the image source data in a data member of your fragment or activity that hosts the `ImageView`.

Comment: I have a resource ID for the image, should I use getResourceId and save that into the bundle?

Comment: @user1409172: I do not know what "getResourceId" you are referring to. That being said, storing the resource ID in the `Bundle` should work fine.

Comment: seems the "getResourcesId" was something someone made for their purposes that I stumbled across, but you and that pointed me in the right direction and I found what I spent the better part of the morning looking for. Thanks for helping a self taught noob learn something and get working results :)

Answer (score -1):

Here's what worked for me:

I first stored the bitmap's state in onSavedInstanceState:

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)
{
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putParcelable(BITMAP, bitmap);
}
```

Then, I retrieved and loaded it in onRestoreInstanceState:

```
@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        if(savedInstanceState != null)
        {
            bitmap = (Bitmap) savedInstanceState.getParcelable(BITMAP);
            loadImg.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
}
```

Comment: onSaveInstanceState() callback is not designed to carry large objects (such as bitmaps) and the data within it must be serialized then deserialized, which can consume a lot of memory and make the configuration change slow.